# как подружить плагин бекграунда на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Добрый вечер. 
вот плагин http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Суть в том что на [этом](http://www.safeit.su/) сайте установлен модуль, который хорошо работает в горизонтальном режиме, но если на телефоне смотреть вертикально, то изображение не обрезается лишнее по бокам, а пропорционально все посередине экрана.

Данный плагин-демка нормально работает.

Помогите его прикрутить или может есть решение как поправить текущий модуль (Fun Supersized)?

**Обновление**

Фремворк полностью адаптивный. Установлен Helix3. Тут дело в самом модуле, мне кажется.

Взял другой скрипт BACKSTRETCH. В тестовой папке на пк все работает.  Прописываю на сайте в index.php не работает.

```
<script src="../test/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../test/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script>
    $.backstretch([
      "pot-holder.jpg",
      "coffee.jpg",
      "dome.jpg"
    ], {
        fade: 750,
        duration: 4000
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что происходит конфликт jQuery, так как 1 раз уже подключен в шаблоне. Когда подключаю непосредственно перед скриптом, чтобы тот работал, то перестают работать модули на сайте. Видно как пытается работать скрипт, но ничего не происходит.  – Андрей Щербаков 17 часов назад

Answer (score 1):

ну если использовать [bootstrap-3](http://bootstrap-3.ru/index.php) не судьба то попытайтесь ширину для контейнера который будете подключать задавать не железными пикселями, а в процентах

Comment: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/#test2-1 да но здесь ширина то как раз устанговлена

Comment: да этот скрипт я и не могу запустить.

Comment: да этот скрипт я и не могу запустить.
прописал простой вроде скрипт на слайд изображения, локально работает на сайте нет.  Не понимаю причину. Можете подсказать? сейчас на сайте пустая страница.

Comment: пути проверяли работают? На те файлы ссылается ?

Comment: такое ощущение что скрипт просто не запускается

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.backstretch is not a function 
Вот что пишет код страницы. просто не является функцией.

Comment: это правельный путь ./test/jquery.backstretch.js?

Comment: папка тест лежит в корне шаблона. 
home/домен/сайт/docs/templates/shaper_cuisine/

Comment: ругается не на пути, а на то что $.backstretch не является функцией.

Comment: правильно значит <script src="../test/jquery.backstretch.js"></script> не подключен если там эта функция прописана

Comment: дописал <script src="test/jquery.js"></script> ошибка исчезла, но изображение не выводится.

Comment: заработало вроде но изображения нет.
видно как появился Div class="backstretch" .....

Comment: говорю же проблема не с скриптами а с тем что не находится или скрипт или картинка проверяйте пути если стоит mozila поставте firebag или ctrl + shift+i и смотрите пути что где находится

Comment: правильные пути. <img src="test/coffee.jpg"/> так выводится